# ImageView.setBackgroundResource

Tags: android, image, android-studio

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
> android.widget.ImageView.setBackgroundResource(int)' on a null object
> reference
> at com.Adapter.MessageAdapter.onBindViewHolder(MessageAdapter.java:240)
> at com.Adapter.MessageAdapter.onBindViewHolder(MessageAdapter.java:37)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7093)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7172)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6037)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6304)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6143)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6139)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next

```
 public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public ImageView read_chat;

}
```

**onBindViewHolder**

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MessageAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    int type = holder.getItemViewType();
    Chat chat = mChat.get(position);

    if (chat.isIsseen()) {
        holder.read_chat. setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_check_double_fill_read);    
    } else {
        holder.read_chat. setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_check_double_fill);
    }

}
```

**ViewHolder view**

```
public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
super(itemView);

  read_chat = itemView.findViewById(R.id.read_chat);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you did in your onCreateViewHolder function, but generally when I see this it's because you inflated the wrong layout. Make sure you are inflating your list_item xml layout. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.your_selected_image));
```